# Unbrick a Steam Controller

Tags: linux, steam

My Steam Controller for some reason got bricked and it won't turn on.

Is there a way to unbrick a Steam Controller?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

To unbrick a SteamController, or to just change its firmware, plug it via USB while keeping the Right Trigger down.

A new USB device will appear (called "CRP DISABLD").
There, you will find a file: `firmware.bin`.
You can replace it with a new (and working) firmware.

On Windows, you can copy the new file over the old one.

On a Linux box, instead, you have to open the terminal and give this command:

```
cd /the-path-to-CRP-DISABLD/

dd conv=nocreat,notrunc oflag=direct bs=512 \
    if=~/my-working-firmware.bin of=./firmware.bin
```

WARNING:
Copying the file directly won't work under Linux!

Via:
http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse/discussions/1/558746745556741615/#c558746995002710011